# Script working fine through browser, but through commandline

Tags: php, command-line

I wrote a script that is accessible through a public URL and it is working fine.

When I execute the script over commandline, I'm only getting php errors. Don't understand why it is not running from command line. What differences do I need to get in mind when running a script from command line or through a browser?

Command:

```
[user@domain ~]$ /usr/local/bin/php /home/user/domains/url/public_html/soap/mail.php
```

Errors:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './php_soap.dll' - ./php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Warning: include(/dbconnect-soap.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/domains/url/public_html/soap/export.php on line 7

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/dbconnect-soap.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/user/domains/url/public_html/soap/export.php on line 7

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/user/domains/url/public_html/soap/export.php on line 10
```

Comment: can you try "cd /home/user/domains/url/public_html/soap/; php mail.php" ?

Comment: `Warning: include(/dbconnect-soap.inc.php)` - Looks like you need to work on improving your paths, so they are all relative.

Comment: They where relative, didn't work. Now I made the first one with full url and still doesn't work through command line. I will continue working on this tomorrow!

Comment: @mulaz, running that command gives the same errors. I'm running out of option...

Comment: YES, got it running!!! Needed to comment (disable) `extension=php_soap.dll` in php.ini!

Comment: It is possible that the .ini used by your terminal and web server are different. To check one used by terminal, type `php --ini`, to check one used by web server, return `phpinfo();` to your web page.